# CMake | Why Doesn't Start?

Tags: cmake

I have checked out the project on two different platforms and they give me -

on Ubuntu (have installed cmake and ccmake)

```
$ make
cd .build && make --no-print-directory
make[1]: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

on Mac OS X (it starts off ...)

```
$ make
touch .configured
cd .build && cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
```

It seems like Ubuntu is still trying to compile using make?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmake is a generator for build-system control files. It does not drive the build by itself, but is relies on external tools like make, nmake or some GUIs to build the software. The `cd .build && cmake ..` line in the osx build only updates the build system files, the build itself is driven by make there.

The error on the ubunto box probably is that there is no Makefile in .build, which means that cmake wasn't executed there, or it failed there previously. You can run cmake by hand with `cd .build && cmake ..`.

Answer (score 0):

If there's a `configure` script in the project, can you try:

```
./configure
make
```

Comment: Hm... It might be that it's a problem with the project setup then.